# Find the Pre-Image of $\ q\ $, where $\ q^{-1}(S)\ $, where $\ S=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

> Let $\ f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ be given by $\ f(x,y)=y(x-y)\ $ and let $\ q:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}\ $ be given by $\ q(r,\theta)=(r \ \text{cos}(\theta),r \ \text{sin}(\theta))$. Find the pre-image $\ q^{-1}(S)\ $, where $\ S=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$.

I have found that the pre-image of $\ f\ $ is the set $\ f^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: y(x-y)\geq 0\}$. Is it also true that $S$ is a closed?

To find $\ q^{-1}(S)\ $, I thought this would correspond to where $\ (r,\theta)\geq S$. But I am very confused on how to proceed. I don't have the intuition of what to do next.

Comment: The preimage of a closed (respectively open) set by a continuous function is closed (respectively open).

Comment: So $S$ is closed?

Comment: $S$ is closed because $f$ is continuous. So $q^{-1}[S]$ will also be closed for the same reason.

Comment: I am required to find $q^{-1}$, not to sure if it's closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition:

$$q^{-1}(S)=\{(r,\theta)\,\colon q(r,\theta)\in S\}$$

Then,

$$q(r,\theta)\in S\iff q(r,\theta)\in f^{-1}([0,+\infty))\iff f(q(r,\theta))\geq 0.$$

This yields

$$ r\sin(\theta)(r\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta))\geq 0$$

Calculating, I obtained that this happens if and only if

$$r^2(\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))\geq 0$$

Maybe you should apply some trigonometric identity to ''simplify'' this result

Comment: Thank you. May I just ask, how would you graph this? I plugged this expression into desmos, but I'm unsure of how to graph this without the use of software.

Comment: Don't know if you already tried, but my first attempt would be to consider $(r,\theta)$ as polar coordinates. Or maybe just try out Wolfram if you're lazy.

Comment: can the expression be simplified any further?